# Raster Package Install Failure [R linux]

Tags: r, linux, raster

I keep trying to install the r "raster" package via `install.packages("raster")`  but get the error:

```
: line 1: 17919 Aborted '/home/support/apps/cports/rhel-6.x86_64/gnu/R/3.4.3/lib64/R/bin/R' --no-save --slave 2>&1 < '/tmp/RtmpFd4ztL/file42e09226d747'
ERROR: loading failed
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I am on linux:
x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: It works for CRAN and for me on  `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS`

Comment: @RobertHijmans, I think it was my own library issue, I didn't have the proper permissions to write to the library I was trying to install to. Thanks for Raster btw, I use it all the time for spatial analysis.